# RabbitMQ Durable queue on disk node

Tags: rabbitmq

I was reading through the documentation of RabbitMQ on their website and came across two terminologies which seem to be doing the same thing - "[Durable Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability)" and "[Disk Node](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#cluster-node-types)". As per the documentation if I make a Disk Node, all data except messages, message store indices, queue indices and other node state (not sure what are the other node states). 
So, if I make my node a `Disk Node`, do I still need to mark my queue as `durable` to survive broker restarts ?

Same question goes for `durable exchanges` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk nodes and durable queues are two different concepts within RabbitMQ.

RabbitMQ maintains certain internal information (such as users, passwords, vhosts, ...) within specific `mnesia` tables. Disk nodes store these tables on disk. As the [related documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#cluster-node-types) states:

> This does not include messages, message store indices, queue indices and other node state.

To ensure durability/persistence of exchanges, queues or messages you need to explicitly state it when you declare/publish them.